# Trying to infinitely loop a complex css animation (border runs around edge of a circle)

Tags: css, css-animations

I'm trying to create an infinite animation where a new stroke around a circle runs around the circumference. Initially the stroke is blue, then when it reaches 360 degrees, it appears to disappear in the same direction. But essentially, a similar animation is running on another group of elements in which the colors are reversed.

I'd like to have this loop infinitely as a loading state. Right now I can get the described behavior to run once. I'm stuck on having it loop, meaning the blue border returns again after it disappears and so on. Snippet is included as a demo -

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.outer, .inner, .cover {
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.outer {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, transparent 0%, transparent 50%, #7db9e8 50%, #7db9e8 100%);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

.outer.opp {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #7db9e8 0%, #7db9e8 50%, transparent 50%, transparent 100%);
}

.inner {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, transparent 0%, transparent 50%, #ccc 50%, #ccc 100%);
  padding: 5px;
  -webkit-animation: spin 5s 2s linear forwards;
}

.inner.opp {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #ccc 0%, #ccc 50%, transparent 50%, transparent 100%);
  -webkit-animation: spin2 5s 7s linear forwards;
}

.cover {
  background: #ccc;
  height: 190px;
  width: 190px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  left: 5px;
  z-index: 5;
}

img {
  margin-left: 35px;
  margin-top: 45px;
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0);
  }
  99.99% {
    background: linear-gradient(to right, transparent 0%, transparent 50%, #ccc 50%, #ccc 100%);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-180deg);
    background: linear-gradient(to right, transparent 0%, transparent 50%, transparent 50%, transparent 100%);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin2 {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0);
  }
  99.99% {
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #ccc 0%, #ccc 50%, transparent 50%, transparent 100%);
  }
  100% {
    background: linear-gradient(to right, transparent 0%, transparent 50%, transparent 50%, transparent 100%);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-180deg);
  }
}

/****** Start css for gray border animation *******/

.gray {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-animation: appear 0s 12s forwards;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
}

.gray .outer {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, transparent 0%, transparent 50%, #ccc 50%, #ccc 100%);
}

.gray .outer.opp {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #ccc 0%, #ccc 50%, transparent 50, transparent 100%);
}

.gray .inner {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, transparent 0%, transparent 50%, #7db9e8 50%, #7db9e8 100%);
  -webkit-animation: spin-gray 5s 12s linear forwards;
}

.gray .inner.opp {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #7db9e8 0%, #7db9e8 50%, #ccc 50%, #ccc 100%);
  -webkit-animation: spin-gray2 5s 17s linear forwards;
}

@-webkit-keyframes appear {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin-gray {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0);
  }
  99.99% {
    background: linear-gradient(to right, transparent 0%, transparent 50%, #7db9e8 50%, #7db9e8 100%);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-180deg);
    background: linear-gradient(to right, transparent 0%, transparent 50%, transparent 50%, transparent 100%);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin-gray2 {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-180deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="opp outer">
  <div class="opp inner">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="gray">
  <div class="opp outer">
    <div class="opp inner">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="cover">
<img src="http://media.giphy.com/media/aHKpXstxvNf56/giphy.gif" height="90"></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out. Used two clipped divs overlaying the div to be revealed. In the clipped divs are a single div with rounded corners. Each is associated with a looping animation. One is delayed to simulate a single seamless effect. Not a perfect solution since the blue is peeking a bit outside the gray circle, but not bad.

However, this clipping property is not supported in IE, FF, and some versions of Android 4. *sigh*

```css
.blue-circle {
  background: blue;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 150px;
  position: relative;
  width: 150px;
}

.cover {
  background: lightgray;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 130px;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 10px;
  width: 130px;
}

.left-half, .right-half {
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 50%;
}

.left-half {
  left: 0;
}

.left-half-circle {
  background: lightgray;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  width: 200%;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(50% 0, 0 0, 0 100%, 50% 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0, 0 0, 0 100%, 50% 100%);
  -webkit-animation: rotate-half-circle 16s 4s linear infinite;
  -webkit-transform: translatez(0);
}

.right-half {
  position: relative;
}

.right-half-circle {
  background: lightgray;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  width: 200%;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 50% 0, 50% 100%, 100% 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 50% 0, 50% 100%, 100% 100%);
  -webkit-animation: rotate-half-circle 16s 0s linear infinite forwards;
  -webkit-transform: translatez(0);
}

@-webkit-keyframes rotate-half-circle {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  25% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
  75% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="blue-circle">
  <div class="left-half">
    <div class="left-half-circle">
    </div>
  </div><!--
  --><div class="right-half">
    <div class="right-half-circle">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="cover-wrapper">
    <div class="cover">
      <img src="http://media.giphy.com/media/aHKpXstxvNf56/giphy.gif" height="90" style="margin-top:15px;">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```